# JavaScript setInterval animation creates gibberish without error in the console

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, animation

I'm trying to create a simple animation with `setInterval`, and I'm testing it on a Python SimpleHTTPServer because I had some cross-origin issues earlier. There is no error in the console when I load the page, and I can see the loading overlay properly, and then the page just becomes gibberish (see images below) although the console shows it is loading image properly. I'm wondering what is wrong. Thanks!

[image: gibberish on the page]

(The gibberish is really long, so this screenshot is just part of it.)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>fish</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./assets/style.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="overlay">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/KUJoe.gif">
        </div>
        <div id="fish" style="width:100px; height:100px;"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(window).on("load", function(){
                $("#overlay").fadeOut();
                var r = 1;
                setInterval(function(){
                    if (r < 5) {
                        $("#fish").load("./assets/images/fish" + r + ".jpeg");
                        r++; 
                    } else {
                        r = 1;
                    }
                    console.log(r);
                    console.log("./assets/images/fish" + r + ".jpeg");
                }, 100);
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Although you are indicating that the encoding is `utf-8` are you sure you actually saved the file using that encoding?

Comment: @ScottMarcus Yes, I just checked again to make sure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you say this:

```
$("#fish").load("./assets/images/fish" + r + ".jpeg");
```

...you are loading the data in the jpeg file as text within the `#fish` element - that is, you are doing the equivalent of trying to open a jpeg file in Notepad.

What you probably want to do is have an `<img>` element and set its `src` to that jpeg file - either change the `<div>` to be an `<img>` or add an `<img>` within the `<div>`:

```
<div style="width:100px; height:100px;"><img id="fish"></div>

// and then
$("#fish").prop("src", "./assets/images/fish" + r + ".jpeg");
```

Note that for smooth animation you probably want to "preload" all of the images, then use `setInterval()` *after* that to switch between them.

Comment: ok when you say "preload" all the images first - didn't I already do that with `$(window).on("load", function(){...};)`, or there is something else I should do?

Comment: The browser doesn't know about your fish jpegs until the JS runs, so it won't start downloading any given image until you set the `src` to that image's URL. If there are only four jpegs it might be easier to just create them as individual `<img>` elements that start out hidden with CSS, and then use JS to change the styles to show them one at a time, because then the window on load function will run *after* the images are all downloaded. Alternatively there are ways to "preload" them from JS, which I can't fit in a comment...

Comment: no, there are more of the images - maybe 50 of them. Ok, I will look into the "preload" options. Thanks!

Comment: Cool. Obviously if you get stuck with preloading you can ask another question, but I think that is a separate issue to what this question was about.